# Cycle through Terraform list

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

If we create multiple `aws_instance` resources:

```
variable "cluster_size" {
  type = number
  default = 4
}

variable "private_subnets" {
  type = list(string)
  default = ["subnet-a", "subnet-b", "subnet-c"]
}

resource "aws_instance" "cassandra" {
  instance_type = var.instance_type
  count         = var.cluster_size
  ami           = var.ami
  key_name      = var.security_key.name
  subnet_id     = var.private_subnets[count.index]
}
```

as you can see I have 3 private subnets, but 4 hosts to run. How to cycle through the list of `private_subnets`?

So

- host 0 = subnet-a
- host 1 = subnet-b
- host 2 = subnet-c
- host 3 = subnet-a *(i.e. cycle to the first element).*

So for example Python has has [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle)

How to achieve the cycle in Terraform's declarative language?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a cycle function but would using var.private_subnets[count.index % length(private_subnets)] work - i.e using the remainder of dividing the count by the number of subnets) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`element` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/element.html) automatically does this, wrapping around at the end of the sequence. It's pretty much the main use of that function since they introduced the slice notation with square brackets that you're using there.

```
variable "cluster_size" {
  type = number
  default = 4
}

variable "private_subnets" {
  type = list(string)
  default = ["subnet-a", "subnet-b", "subnet-c"]
}

resource "aws_instance" "cassandra" {
  instance_type = var.instance_type
  count         = var.cluster_size
  ami           = var.ami
  key_name      = var.security_key.name
  subnet_id     = element(var.private_subnets, count.index)
}
```

Alternatively, you could take the modulo by using the `%` operator just like you can in other programming languages:

```
variable "cluster_size" {
  type = number
  default = 4
}

variable "private_subnets" {
  type = list(string)
  default = ["subnet-a", "subnet-b", "subnet-c"]
}

resource "aws_instance" "cassandra" {
  instance_type = var.instance_type
  count         = var.cluster_size
  ami           = var.ami
  key_name      = var.security_key.name
  subnet_id     = var.private_subnets[count.index % length(var.private_subnets)]
}
```

The first option is more common when needing to wrap around with the square bracket slice notation more common when you don't need to wrap around.